# Airflow - Change the default ui_color

Tags: airflow

There is a way to change the default **ui_color** for an airflow operator?

The only way I found is to write my own operator and inherit from the specific airflow operator, But it's too complicated for this simple change.

I dont know why, but the default colors are very similar, look at my own spark wrapper against the default python/kube/bash operators
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPzf4.png)

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can overwrite the value after importing the module, like below. You could then define you colorset once and apply import it to all your DAGs for instance:

```
from airflow.operators.oracle_operator import OracleOperator
OracleOperator.ui_color = '#0000FF'
### your DAG code below
```